# Combining AsyncSeq.ofObservableBuffered and AsyncSeq.cache

Tags: f#

I've a requirement where I need to cache the results of an event into an `asyncSeq` and iterate though this `asyncSeq` once a long running function has returned. The idea here is to iterate through profiles and apply `runFunction` to both the cached results as well as the future results (hence the use of `ofObservableBuffered`).

I would like to know what's the best way to do this. I'm using `AsyncSeq.Cache` as shown below. `AsyncSeq.Cache` is using a combination of `ResizeArray` and `MailboxProcessor` to accomplish the caching. However, I'm not sure if this will lead to a memory leak.

```
let profiles =
    client.ProfileReceived
    |> AsyncSeq.ofObservableBuffered
    |> AsyncSeq.cache
    
do! longRunningFunction()

do! function2 (fun _ ->
    async {
        do! profiles
            |> AsyncSeq.iterAsync(fun profile -> async {
                do! runFunction profile
                return()
            })
    }
```

Comment: This looks like an incomplete code segment. Can we see the rest of the CE please.

Answer (score 2):

Your question does not give all details about your scenario, but I think the answer is that you do not need `AsyncSeq.cache` and using just `AsyncSeq.ofObservableBuffered` should be enough.

Asynchronous sequences generate values on demand ("pull based") which means that elements are only generated when needed. Observables are "push based" which means that they generate data whenever the data source decides.

To map from "push based" to "pull based", you either need to drop data (when the listener is not ready to accept the next item) or cache data. If you cache, then you may potentially run out of memory if the producer is faster than the consumer - but this is inevitable by design problem. The `AsyncSeq.ofObservableBuffered` function does the latter.

`AsyncSeq.cache` is useful if you have one data source, but want to consume it from multiple different places. Without this, the data source will generate data repeatedly for each consumer, so `cache` enables generating the data just once. However, if you are using `ofObservableBuffered` is already doing the same thing - i.e. caching all the generated values.

I believe the only reason why you might want to keep `cache` is if you subscribe to the observable at a later time - in which case, it would keep elements generated before you started consuming values (and use two caches, one of which would keep not-yet-consumed elements (possibly safe if the consumer is fast enough) and one which would keep all the already generated elements (certainly potential to run out of memory over a longer period of time)).

Comment: I was also expecting `profiles` to cache the data after using `let profiles = client.ProfileReceived |> AsyncSeq.ofObservableBuffered` . The idea was to start using values in `profiles` after the long running operation. `profiles` would've cached all the values while the long running async operation was executing. However, this is not the case. `profiles` remain empty when trying to iterate using `AsyncSeq.iterAsync` after the long running operation.

Comment: @su8898 I think `ofObservableBuffered` only starts storing & buffering values when you create a subscription - so if you started the iteration before the long-running operation (possibly just by calling `GetEnumerator` but without actually iterating over the elements), that should be enough to start the caching.